# Call to native DLL fails from a .NET Windows service

Tags: .net, windows, windows-services, pinvoke, unmanaged

I have a 3rd party API in the form of a native dll that I call from C# using `DllImport`. This native dll depends on the 3rd party application being open.

When I run the code normally the API does what is expected and drives the application. However, when I run the same code as a Windows service, even as myself, the API returns the same (undocumented) error code that I have seen when the application is closed; process explorer confirms that the native dll is correctly loaded from the application directory.

What could be causing this and how might I be able to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to use a dummy unmanaged dll to load to determine where the error happens: in p/invoke or in your dll itself?

Comment: @abatishchev - no, however it definitely isn't a problem with the service, I've stripped the service back so that all it does is p/invoke the unmanaged dll. I think that Fadrian Sudaman is correct when he says that the issue may be something to do with the application and the service running in different sessions, or something like that. The 3rd party software is pretty ropey to say the least.

Comment: So p/invoke from console application works fine, and doesn't from windows service?

Comment: @abatishchev - yes that's the situation.

Comment: I experienced problems when the dll was in a path containing blank spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit old, but it came up as one of the top results in a search. So I asume my data would still be helpfull.

> I have a 3rd party API in the form of a native dll that I call from C# using DllImport. This native dll depends on the 3rd party application being open.

The (t)rusty Office Interop DLL is the same way. You are actually starting a background instance of the Office Programm in question.
The Background Instance needs an interactive Session, even if it does not show anything (design asumptions/mistakes at work).
Services do not run in an [interactive session since Vista](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Using the override is not recommended practice.
That is one of the (3?) reasons to not use Office Interop anymore.

Possible workarounds:

1. stop using a service. The Windows Task sheduler can do jsut about the same work, while giving you full interactive sessions. Even MS themself started to move stuff out of services, into the Sheduler whereever possible
2. move the DLL access into a Helper process. That one can run in an interactive session. Use any way of interprocess communication to talk between the helper and the main service. This pattern is primarily used to work with x32 only dll from a x64 programm, but it should work here too. Both the manifest and Process.Start() have a way to start a programm interactively from a Service.

Based on one of the comments it appears you choose option 2, but using a Webservice instead.
Unfortunately Webserices/Webapplications are usually run as Windows Service. And that is before you consider that they run under some of the most restrictive rights (since they are web reachable).
So it would just get you back to square 1 or even another step backwards to square 0.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell, but there is three possibilities I can think of:

- Your service has UI component that require "interact with desktop" option checked
- The working directory for windows service is %WinDir%\system32 (e.g. C:\windows\system32) and your dll have code that uses relative path reference to other resources that can't be found
- Your service uses netpipe communication with the application that run in two different sessions

Comment: I've tried 1. and that has no effect. The code can be run from any location without supplying any paths, so that rules out 2. However, 3 sounds likely - the service is running in a different session / domain from the application and this is causing it not to work. How can I verify this and what if any are the workarounds?

Comment: Unfortunately not much. Session isolation is part of OS security. You can search on stackoverflow or goggle along the line of "netpipe session isolation" and try the suggested workarounds but personally I think it will be quite a challenging journey.

Comment: I think the hack I'm going to go with is to wrap the dll in a web service that will run on start up and then call through to that web service from the web service. That should almost definitely work. I'm hoping the project gets canned soon anyway :)

Comment: Using a web service as an intermediary does the job. It's a nasty solution, but it is a nasty piece of software, so fits well with the overall architecture :)

Comment: look like you just proved another legacy system integration with WS :p

Comment: If only this were a legacy system. This is a new proposed global enterprise solution! Like I said, I'm hoping it gets canned soon :p

Answer (score 0):

If you have to call native dll from a service, before starting it, try change the current directory like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new XYZService()
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
}
```

After this, the service has no trouble to find the Native DLL's without changing Environment variables or without moving the native DLL's into the system folder.